# What is the domain of the metric function (Flash card from Anki Deck)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

[Flash card from Anki Deck (https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/475919945) question about a metric](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lswTp.png)

> A metric $d$ on a set $X$ is a function $d\colon X\times X\to[0,\infty)$ with the following three propreties:
>
> What is this called?
> $$d(x,y)=0 \Leftrightarrow x=y, \text{ for all } x,y\in X$$
> Triangle inequality
> $$d(x,y)+d(y,z)\ge d(x,z), \text{ for all }x,y,z\in X$$
> Symmetry $$d(x,y)=d(y,z)\text{ for all }x,y\in X$$
>
> A *metric space* is a set together with a metric on it, or more formally, a pair $(X,d)$ where $X$ is a set and $d$ is a metric on $X$.

Basically I am wondering why the metric is simply a Cartesian product of $X$, why not a countably finite product of $X$ or even an infinite product? It almost seems that the triangle inequality suggest that $D\colon X \times X \times X \to [0,+\infty)$.

I have little formal education in maths outside of physics (which I have a minor in)

Comment: A metric gives you the distance between two points, so it's a function of two variables.

Answer (score 2):

A metric measures the distanc between *two points* so it's a function (with real values) that has to be defined on $X \times X$; it has $2$ inputs and one value. The triangle inequality only talks about distances between pairs (and their sum), not about a distance for triples..

Comment: I read this in April and didn't understand, today I do. Thank you

Comment: @KeeganPaice I’m glad it helped you, then.